# Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, locale

This error occurred when I rebooted ubuntu18.04.

[image]

Maybe it was because I accidentally deleted the native Chinese language of the system before restarting it. I can't turn on my laptop now. What should I do now?